# Numbering figures and tables in part

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, floats, numbering, parts

Here is the deal: I'm writing my thesis and I divided the thesis into 3 parts, each part had 2 chapters.

At the beginning of each part, I added two pages of introduction. However, the numbering of figure and table in these two pages followed the previous chapter. Here is the structure:

> Chap1: Introduction Part1 (2 pages of introduction of this part)
>
> Chap2: ...
>
> Chap3: ... Part2 etc.

In the two pages of Introduction, the numbering followed the previous chapter (i.e. chapter 1).

I want to change the numbering to `I.1`, `I.2`, etc. and make it appear in `List of table` and `figure`. Anyone can help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: try using `\numberwithin{figure}{part}` and `\numberwithin{table}{part}`.  (`\numberwithin` is defined in `amsmath`.  it would certainly have been a useful addition to the latex base.)

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice. You can fill with dummy text as provided by the `lipsum` package. And: Welcome!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I understand your setup correctly, you have (i) intro-like components following each `\part` command but *before* the first `\chapter` command occurs and (ii) you have floats within these intro-like components. Moreover, it would appear that your floats are currently numbered by `chapter`. I'd say you have to options: (A) insert new instructions of the type `\chapter{Introductory Remarks}`, so that a new chapter number is created and is made available to the floats; and (B) change the float numbering setup from per-chapter to per-part (as suggested by @barbarabeeton).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @Mico: yes, that what I want to do. I did try what you and Barbara Beeton suggest. It worked. Thanks all.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you make your comment here an answer?

Answer (score 1):

try using `\numberwithin{figure}{part}` and `\numberwithin{table}{part}`.

`\numberwithin` is defined in `amsmath`. (it would certainly have been a useful addition to the latex base.)

two other packages also provide similar/related facilities:

- `chngcntr` -- has the commands `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` (and starred versions)
- `remreset` -- has one "internal" command (with `@`) that provides a way to undo an automatic reset

see the package documentation for details.